# When is "is_initial" true in Dygraph's drawCallback?

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I have a Dygraphs chart that works perfectly when I provide a file URL for a data source.  When I embedded the data directly into the HTML wrapper, however, the functions in my drawCallback don't fire.  Tracing with Firebug, I find that `is_initial` is `True` when I load the page with the URL reference, but `False` when I embed the data (and labels) in native format, even if I place  `onLoad="drawCallback(vGraph,True);"` within the `<body>` tag.  I've "solved" this by setting my own variable to test for first-time execution.

Here's the original, functional, code for an external data source:

```
var vGraph = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("dgraphChartContainer"),
ExternalDataSource.csv,
{  //options
   connectSeparatedPoints: true,
   labelsDiv: "dygraphLabelsContainer",
   ...
   }
);

vGraph.updateOptions({
   highlightCallback: function(event, xdate, points_array, rowNumber, seriesName) {
   ...
   },
   unhighlightCallback: function(event) {
   ...
   },
   drawCallback: function(g, is_initial) {
      if (!is_initial) return;
      buildTagList(vGraph.getLabels());
      mySeriesColors = vGraph.getColors();
      buildStyleDefinitions();
   }
});
```

As I said, this works great, even with the blind `g` parameter in the drawCallback.

This is the work-around I developed for the scenario when I embed the data source.

```
var vFirstTime = true;
var vGraph = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("dgraphChartContainer"),
[
[ new Date("2011/10/15 00:04:55"),null,null,-9.2,null,null,null,null,null,null],
[ new Date("2011/10/24 10:39:32"),null,null,null,null,null,-9.2,null,null,null],
...
[ new Date("2011/10/25 21:02:30"),null,null,null,null,null,null,null,20.3,null],
[ new Date("2013/10/28 08:49:52"),null,null,-17.9,null,null,null,null,null,null]
],
{  //options
   labels: ["Event_Date","code-32565","code-32566","code-32568","code-32569","code-32573","code-32574","code-32575","code-32577","code-32578"],
   connectSeparatedPoints: true,
   labelsDiv: "dygraphLabelsContainer",
   ...
   }
);

vGraph.updateOptions({
   highlightCallback: function(event, xdate, points_array, rowNumber, seriesName) {
   ...
   },
   unhighlightCallback: function(event) {
   ...
   },
   // drawCallback: function(g, is_initial) {
   // if (!is_initial) return;
   drawCallback: function() {
      if (!vFirstTime) return;
      buildTagList(vGraph.getLabels());
      mySeriesColors = vGraph.getColors();
      buildStyleDefinitions();
      vFirstTime=false;
   }
});
```

Is there something I can do to use `is_initial` in my `drawCallback` call regardless of the data source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example will work if you move your callbacks into the constructor:

```js
var vGraph = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("dgraphChartContainer"),
ExternalDataSource.csv,
{  //options
   connectSeparatedPoints: true,
   labelsDiv: "dygraphLabelsContainer",
   highlightCallback: function(event, xdate, points_array, rowNumber, seriesName) {
   ...
   },
   unhighlightCallback: function(event) {
   ...
   },
   drawCallback: function(g, is_initial) {
      if (!is_initial) return;
      buildTagList(vGraph.getLabels());
      mySeriesColors = vGraph.getColors();
      buildStyleDefinitions();
   },
   ...
});
```

So, what's going on here?

The drawCallback gets fired with `is_initial = true` when the chart draws for the first time. In your original code, this happens after the XMLHttpRequest for the data comes back.

The order of operations is:

1. constructor
2. updateOptions
3. drawCallback(is_initial=true)

When you inline your data, dygraphs doesn't need to wait for the XHR to come back. Now, the order of operations is:

1. constructor
2. drawCallback(is_initial=true)
3. updateOptions
4. drawCallback(is_initial=false)

The second drawCallback happens because you called `updateOptions()`. So drawCallback *is* getting fired with `is_initial = true`, it's just that you're not listening for it early enough.

dygraphs provides a [.ready()](http://dygraphs.com/jsdoc/symbols/Dygraph.html#ready) method to let you avoid all this intricacy. You may be happier using it instead:

```js
var vGraph = new Dygraph( ... );
vGraph.ready(function() {
  buildTagList(vGraph.getLabels());
  mySeriesColors = vGraph.getColors();
  buildStyleDefinitions();
});
```